# Remove HTML tag (Python)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML code

```
<span><s>Something</s>Anything</span>
```

I would like to remove the span tag, returning the HTML code

```
<s>Something></s>
```

I am using the beautifulsoup library

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
soup.span.unwrap()
```

But that returns -> `<s>Something</s>Anything`

Comment: Is there any more HTML? or that's everything?

Comment: Yes, there are. However, I can handle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code:

```
s1 = soup.span.s
soup.span.replaceWith(s1)
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<html><body><s>Something</s></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the `<s>` part, why not just filter that out instead of removing?

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """
<span><s>Something</s>Anything</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, "lxml")
print(soup.find("s"))
```

This gets you:

```
<s>Something</s>
```

Should you have more of those `<span>` tags with `<s>` inside, you could go for something like this:

```
sample = """
<span><s>Something</s>Anything</span>
<span><s>More of Something</s>Less of Anything</span>
"""
print([t.find("s") for t in soup.find_all("span")])
```

To get this:

```
[<s>Something</s>, <s>More of Something</s>]
```

However, if you want to remove the tags, then you'll end up with an empty `HTML` (at least in this simple case).

See this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """
<span><s>Something</s>Anything</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, "lxml")

for tag in soup.find_all(True):
    if tag.name == "span":
        tag.extract()
print(soup)
```

Produces this:

```
<html><head></head><body>
</body></html>
```

Or, shorter, with a list comprehension:

```
print([t.extract() for t in soup.find_all("span")])
```

Gives: `[]`

So, I guess, your best bet is to filter the unwanted tags out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to remove the span tag because I want to save the HTML code without the span tags.

Answer (score 0):

you want `<s>` tags or innerHTML of `<span>`?

first answer give you a code to get `<s>` tags or `<s>Something></s>`

To get innerHTML of `<span>` or value `<s>Something</s>Anything` use

```
spanTag.decode_contents()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('home.html', 'r') as html_file:
   content = html_file.read()

   soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
   print(soup.prettify()) # this part makes the output look better
```